# Keras LSTM network, Softmax/Embedding output as input for each time step (except for time step 0)

Tags: keras

I want something simple: a LSTM network (with one LSTM layer) that takes as 1st input (time step 0) a fixed value input, **THEN**, the output of the LSTM must be as follow:

- softmax layer
- then taking the max value of the softmax (see the "Lambda" layer)
- finally, taking this max value and turn it into an Embedding layer

**THEN** I want the output to be used as input for the next time step.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
voc_size = 10

controller_input = keras.Input(shape=(1,1,))

x = layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(controller_input)
x = layers.Dense(voc_size, activation="softmax")(x[0])
x = layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.argmax(x,axis=-1))(x)
x = layers.Embedding( voc_size, 100 )(x)

model = Model(inputs=controller_input, outputs=x)

utils.plot_model(model, to_file="example.png")
```

[image]

But, I don't have the feeling that it is doing what I am thinking of, especially, I don't see how the output (Embedding layer) is feeding the next time step.

Any idea?